# Why doesn't R recognize 'CST' as a valid timezone?

Tags: datetime, r, date, time, timezone

This code works:

```
ISOdatetime(2011,4,7,12,0,0, tz = "EST")
```

This code does not:

```
ISOdatetime(2011,4,7,12,0,0, tz = "CST")
```

I want the central time zone, with no adjustment for daylight savings.  What am I doing wrong?  Where can I find a table of timezones recognized by R?

edit: Thanks for the info Josh, but `ISOdatetime(2011,3,13,2,0,0, tz = "America/Chicago")` yields NA, and is unfortunately a value in my dataset.  Any ideas how to deal with this?  It seems like my dataset is on Chicago time, but does not observe daylight savings time.

Comment: Is the timezone necessary for your purposes, or could you just ignore it and use GMT?

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: For now I will just ignore it and use GMT.  Unfortunately, I have data from several timezone in this manner, and was hoping to make use of R's easy-to-use time zone conversion functions.  If I want to add (or subtract) one hour from a GMT time, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: I would do it how I did it in my answer.  Though I find it curious that your data has timestamps that don't follow the DST conventions of the timezone.  Do your raw data have an explicit timezone (e.g. "2011-03-13 02:00:00 CST"), or could they be GMT already?

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: The raw data does not have an explicit timezone, but it is not GMT.  As far as I can tell, it's GMT-6 exactly. I'll just add 6 hours and treat it as GMT.  Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `?timezone` and the file, `R_HOME/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab`.

There's no such thing as "the central time zone, with no adjustment for daylight savings".  The US central time zone has DST rules and they have changed over the years.  You could always read in your dates as GMT, add 6 hours, then convert to CST6CDT.

```
> .POSIXct(ISOdatetime(2011,3,13,2,0,0, tz="GMT")+3600*6, tz="CST6CDT")
[1] "2011-03-13 03:00:00 CDT"
> .POSIXct(ISOdatetime(2011,3,13,2,0,0, tz="GMT")+3600*6, tz="America/Chicago")
[1] "2011-03-13 03:00:00 CDT"
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Is there any way I can specify "Chicago time with no daylight savings time?"  `ISOdatetime(2011,3,13,2,0,0, tz = "America/Chicago")` yields NA, and is unfortunately a value in my dataset.

Comment: Wow, I don't think I've ever seen a worst documentation page for an R function.

Comment: @Benjamin, as it says in `?timezone`, EST is _not_ US eastern time, it "is a time zone used in Canada _without_ daylight savings time".  It's also defined in `R_HOME/share/zoneinfo/EST`. Note there's no corresponding CST file.  And if you find the documentation bad, you're more than welcome to submit an improvement to R-core. ;-)